# GPG passphrase and secret key export

Tags: encryption, gnupg

Assume that I have a GPG secret key Sk guarded by a passphrase and that I store the key in a safe in case a thief steals my laptop. The safe is itself reliable and secure. Assume also that I am likely to lose my memory in a car accident while catching the thief.

- I wouldn't worry about the thief, as I used the passphrase to create Sk. The best the thief can do is to brute-force my passphrase.
- However, I would worry about myself not being able to remember the key.

Is brute-forcing my own passphrase my only option here?

If so, am I better off storing my passphrase alongside my Sk on a different file in the safe?

Comment: Your question essentially is "How do I remember a password safely?" - Use a password manager or protect your key with a MFA hardware key

Comment: @MechMK1 Not quite. What you suggest can be thought of as a replacement for my "safe". You'd replace my "safe" with an MFA hardware key. As far as I understood, your answer to my question is: yes, you are better off storing your passphrase alongside your Sk (on an MFA hardware key as a replacement to your "safe").